# Is it possible to read table data from images in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, image, dataframe

Is there a way to read images with extensions like .jpeg/.png/.bmp into a pandas dataframe?
The image would be having table data, something like this:

[image]

Please let me know if there is a way of reading table contents from an image to pandas dataframe. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question, now I also wanted to look into it :)

I remembered there are modules to extract Tables as Pandas Dataframe from PDF and HTML.
[link](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/3-techniques-to-extract-tables-as-pandas-dataframe-from-pdf-html-files-9a95c0b55f74)
I am not sure, if it is working for png.,jpeg files.

Also find an github code that is for:  **A table detection, cell recognition and text extraction algorithm to convert tables in images to excel files, using pytesseract and open cv.**
[link](https://gist.github.com/huks0/e48d604fc9dd91731bc687d6e3933db4)

[other related websites](https://towardsdatascience.com/a-table-detection-cell-recognition-and-text-extraction-algorithm-to-convert-tables-to-excel-files-902edcf289ec)

[Microsoft excel tool for getting data via an image](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/insert-data-from-picture-3c1bb58d-2c59-4bc0-b04a-a671a6868fd7)